# Destination of merged PDFs in Automator?

Tags: macos, pdf, automator

Where can I find the PDF merged by the automator?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is placed in a temporary file, with some random name, such as:

```
/var/folders/mt/k2_g0s2x3dl9jpx009p14nmw0000gm/T/JbtgKP.pdf
```

In general they are placed somewhere under `/var/fodlers` directory.

If you want to find where it is, you can open a Terminal and type something like:

```
sudo find /var/folders/ -name "*.pdf"
```

But probably, you'll want to rename and move it where you need, adding `Rename Finder Items` and `Move Finder Items` steps.